# automatically calculate sheet formulas in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook with about 50 sheets and about 15 of them all with the same formulas (different data) that do not calculate unless I physically open the sheet.

If I close the workbook and re-open it, I will have to open each sheet again for the data to be calculated, this is obviously incredibly frustrating!

In the File/Options/Formulas I have workbook calculation set to automatic and I also have the following code in the open workbook to try and resolve it, but unfortunately it's still doesn't work -

`Application.CalculateFullRebuild`

Example of the type of function it is failing to calculate unless I open the file:

```
=LET(projectName, A2, setPrj, ProjectTemplateDataset, setRoster, ProjectRatesTbl, SOMs, $I$1#, namesPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,1), startsPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,5), endsPrj,
 INDEX(setPrj,,6),names, ProjectRatesTbl[Project Name], starts, ProjectRatesTbl[Start Date], ends, ProjectRatesTbl[End Date],
 monthlySalaries, ProjectRatesTbl[Rate (Monthly)], dalySalaries, ProjectRatesTbl[Rate (Day)],empty, ",,",
 SPLIT, LAMBDA(x,case, LET(y, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,x),",",";"), z, FILTER(y, INDEX(y,,1)<>"", NA()),
     IFS(case=0, z,case=1, HSTACK(INDEX(z,,1), 1*CHOOSECOLS(z,2,3)), case=2, 1*z))),
 DEBUG, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(" & ",,x)),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),endsAdj, IF(ends > 0, ends, EOM),
  overlapsPrj, MAP(namesPrj, startsPrj, endsPrj, LAMBDA(namePrj,startPrj,endPrj,
   IF(AND(startPrj <= EOM, endPrj >= SOM), TEXTJOIN(",",,namePrj, MAX(startPrj, SOM), MIN(endPrj, EOM)), empty))),
   setPrjAdj, SPLIT(overlapsPrj,1),
   overlapsRoster, IF(ISNA(ROWS(setPrjAdj)), NA(),
    MAP(INDEX(setPrjAdj,,1), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,2), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,3), LAMBDA(name,start,end,
      LET(found, FILTER(HSTACK(starts, endsAdj, dalySalaries, monthlySalaries), (names= projectName) * (starts <= end)
        * (endsAdj >= start), NA()), IF(AND(ROWS(found)=1, NOT(ISNA(found))),
        TEXTJOIN(",",, MAX(INDEX(found,,1), start), MIN(INDEX(found,,2), end), CHOOSECOLS(found,3,4)), empty)
    )))
  ),setRosterAdj, SPLIT(overlapsRoster,2),
  IF(ISNA(ROWS(setRosterAdj)), 0,
    LET(startEffDates, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,1), endEffDates, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,2),
      effDailySalaries, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,3),  effMonthlySalaries, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,4),
      days, NETWORKDAYS(startEffDates, endEffDates), monthWorkDays, NETWORKDAYS(SOM, EOM),
      actualSalaries, IF(days = monthWorkDays, effMonthlySalaries, effDailySalaries),
      actualDays, IF(days = monthWorkDays, 1, days),
      IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(actualDays, actualSalaries),0)
    ))
  )))
)
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this please?

Comment: Your formulas are pure Excel "built in" formulas?  No UDF?  Having to switch to each tab before the formulas will calculate sounds like a UDF with a bug (eg. implicit sheet reference)

Comment: I've added an example  of the formula above. I don't  believe there's bugs in it, the result is correct when I open the file.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the function above as I had accidentally copied the wrong one in. It references a bunch of tables in another sheet and uses a number of named ranges to reference data in the sheet which in turn is generated by a function pointing at another sheet using `=FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Code Name]=B2), {1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})`

I'm assuming from what you're saying it is something to do with the formula constructions but is there any way to force these calculations on workbook open?

Comment: That's well beyond my Excel formula-fu

Comment: What do you mean by "opening the sheet"? You click on its tab (the thing down, which says e.g. Sheet1)? How do you know that it is not recalculated if not opened?

Comment: because I'm pulling data in to a new sheet from the sheets that are not calculating and the data is 0, hence why I know they're not calculating

Comment: And what would you consider a solution? I mean, it must be a bug in Excel: this formula is full of new functional functions but I don't think that the specification of any of them said that the result depends on the visibility of its sheet. Is it acceptable to you to add some code to your Workbook_Open sub that activates ("opens") each worksheet, one after the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try activating all sheets after the workbook is opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim originalActive As Worksheet: Set originalActive = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets:
        ws.Activate
    Next ws
    originalActive.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: must have been in the middle of writing a solution very much like this when you posted. I have the offending sheets listed in a table so I loop through those rather than all sheets and it works well - just takes a little bit of time.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to call Activate on each of the offending sheets when opening the workbook. I actually have a sheet with all the names of the sheets in it so I loop through them like so :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    
    Dim Wb As Workbook: Set Wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    If Wb.WorkSheetExists("Project Info", Wb) Then
        Dim myTable As ListObject
        Dim myArray As Variant

        Set myTable = Wb.Sheets("Project Info").ListObjects("ProjectInfoTbl")
        Set myArray = myTable.ListColumns("Project Name").Range

        For Each Cell In myArray
            If Wb.WorkSheetExists(Cell.Value, Wb) Then
                Wb.Sheets(Cell.Value).Activate
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```